# pipenv fails to create virtual environment: " Creating virtual environment...AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'select'"

Tags: pipenv

I had a pipenv virtual environment created for this VS Code workspace. It stopped working. I manually deleted that venv based on a similar post here:
[pipenv shell fails to create virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959706/pipenv-shell-fails-to-create-virtual-environment)

Mac M1 macOS Ventura 13.4.1

When I run pipenv install I get the same error. I upgraded to the latest pip. I uninstalled pipenv and reinstalled. All successful. But, I'm still getting this error when trying to create a new virtual environment:
Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3 (3.11.1) to create virtualenv...
⠙ Creating virtual environment...AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'select'

✘ Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.

I tried the solution proposed here and couldn't even get sudo to work.
[pipenv shell failed creating virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013173/pipenv-shell-failed-creating-virtual-environment)
% sudo apt remove pip
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.